# How to repaint static control on changing text?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, c++builder

I handle WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC message to make transparent background for static control:

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
{
SetTextColor((HDC)wParam,RGB(0,0,0));
SetBkMode((HDC)wParam,TRANSPARENT);
HBRUSH return_bush = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
return (LRESULT)return_brush;
}
```

This works fine.
And now I try to change text for static control by calling SendMessage(). But in result new text is placed over the existing text. I think that need to repaint static control.
How to repaint static control? How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your problem (changing text in Transparent Static control) is already on Stackoverflow; See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823883/updating-text-in-a-c-win32-api-static-control-drawn-with-ws-ex-transparent)

Comment: Thanks, but where to insert this code?:
RECT rect;
    HWND hctrl;
    hctrl = GetDlgItem(hwnd, ControlID);
    GetClientRect(hctrl, &rect);
    MapWindowPoints(hctrl, hwnd, (POINT *)&rect, 2);
    InvalidateRect(hwnd, &rect, TRUE);
which WM message to handle?

Comment: Insert the code where you change the text of the static control (after the SendMessage)